# Button of one2many form view in Odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo-8, formview

I would like to ask about one2many field form view with action button.

I have a model with one2many field. I would like to add button in one2many form view, but, when I added that button in view, it only showed in readonly mode. It did not know which model/object should be used, just I think, so how to add the model for that button.

My code like that:

```
class main_model(osv.osv):
    _name = "main.model"
    _columns = {
         'other_model_ids':fields.one2many('other.model','main_id','Other'),
    }
class other_model(osv.osv):
    _name = "other.model"
    _columns = {
        'name':fields.char('Name'),
        'code':fields.char('Code'),
        'main_id':fields.many2one('main.model','Main'),
    }
...
<field name="model">main.model</field>
<field name="type">form</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <field name="other_model_ids">
         <tree string="Other Model">
              <field name="name"/>
              <field name="code"/>
         </tree>
         <form string="Other Model">
              <group>
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <button name="generate_code" string="Generate Code" type="object"/>
                    <field name="code"/>
              </group>
         </form>
    </field>
</field>
...
```

I would like to add that button in one2many form view.

`button name="generate_code" string="Generate Code" type="object"...`

but that button did not know which model belong this. If you know and have some time, please explain me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion:

1.You should define the function under the model:

For example:

```
class other_model(osv.osv):
_name = "other.model"
_columns = {
    'name':fields.char('Name'),
    'code':fields.char('Code'),
    'main_id':fields.many2one('main.model','Main'),
}

@api.one
def generate_code(self):
    pass
```

2.You can try this:

```
<field name="model">main.model</field>
<field name="type">form</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form string="Main Model">
        <notebook>
            <page string="Other Models">
                <field name="Other Model">
                    <tree>
                        <field name="name"/>
                        <field name="code"/>
                        <button name="generate_code" string="Generate Code" type="object"/>
                    </tree>
                </field>
            </page>
        </notebook>
    </form>
</field>
```

I wish this will help you.

Comment: @Melicap I already defined like that. One thing strange is when I only used <tree> tag in view. It knew which object belong that view. When I declared <form> tag in that view, it did not know which object belong that one2many field. What wrong with that. If you know, please explain me. Thanks.

Comment: @Thae Ei Htwe Why you declared in that "Main Model" form? You can declar it's own form like this:

Comment: @Melicap I declared in 'Other Model' form.

Comment: <field name="model">other.model</field>
<field name="type">form</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form string="Other Model">
        <sheet>
            <group>
                <field name="name"/>
                <button name="generate_code" string="Generate Code" type="object"/>
                <field name="code"/>
            </group>
        </sheet>
     </form>
</field>

Comment: @Melicap I already tried like that. But I have no idea why I could not get. :(

Comment: I'm sorry about that.